# Handling left-to-right inside right-to-left paragraphs using Emacs and AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, hebrew, right-to-left, bidi

I'm using Emacs to typeset a document which has English as its main language but which will use Hebrew and Greek as well.

You can see on my screenshot how the `\footnote` command shows two open brackets as opposed to the correct open and close brackets.

```
{\footnoteA{This is a Hebrew related footnote
```

as opposed to the correct way

```
\footnoteA{This is a Hebrew related footnote}
```

The end result however, on the PDF is correct.

[image: Incorrect handling of left-to-right text within a right-to-left paragraph]

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{greek, hebrew}
\setmainfont{SBL BibLit}
\begin{document}
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\begin{hebrew}
  \pstart

בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית\footnoteA{This is a Hebrew related footnote} בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃

  \pend
\end{hebrew}
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\begin{greek}
  \pstart
  Ἐν ἀρχῇ\footnoteA{This is a Greek related footnote} ἐποίησεν ὁ
  θεὸς τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν.
  \pend
\end{greek}
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Column
\end{document}
```

Comment: Having a test file could be useful.

Comment: @giordano I've added a MWE. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has been already asked and **answered** at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19696/620

Answer (score 1):

Emacs version 25.1 added support for Bidirectional Parentheses Algorithm (aka "paired brackets" in UAX 9) which helps a bit: I'm seeing:

[image: visual order: DETAERC DOG footnoteA{this is a hebrew related footnote}\GNINNIGEB EHT NI]

Note backslash is still weirdly placed.

I've never tried but [Emacs bidi](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Bidirectional-Display.html)  is somewhat tweakable (I think it's even partially implemented in Elisp?), so it ought to be possible to further optimize it for mixed LaTeX.  E.g. treating `\` as [weak] LTR character might help?

But whatever you do there will be messy situations.  My favorite strategy is to insert newlines before and after any problematic opposite-direction portions (this btw helps across editors) :

[image: footnote content on its own line]

LaTeX's empty-line-delimits-paragraphs rule makes such newlines usually safe, though sometimes `%` is needed.

Comment: Thank you Beni Cherniavsky-Paskin for the information. Unfortunately I double posted this question here and http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19696/620. Over there a solution was proposed and found.